# Risk of using water-grade copper tube on refrigerant line

Tags: hvac, pipe

If I had to macgyver a bypass on 1/8" distributor tubing using a makeshift ferrule/coupling made of 1/4" pipe that was not ACR grade (thinner wall), because it is very short (1.5") and I don't have 1/4" handy, would that pose a leak hazard? I don't want to have to buy a 10' piece of 1/4" correct pipe just because I need 1.5".

Answer (score 3):

1/8" refrigeration tubing has a service pressure rating of **2613 PSI** [Per this linked page.](https://www.beaconmedaes.com/content/dam/brands/beacon-medaes/documents/lab/applications-and-tools/reference-tools/pressureratingforcopperpipesandtubes.pdf)

1/4" of the same class is rated only 1195, 1/4" ACR (and they list no 1/8" for that) is only 775, and type K (the heaviest water service type) is only 913.

"Macguyvering" refrigeration systems is dubious anywhere, and it's generally illegal to do any work on most refrigeration systems without a license in the USA. Anyway, looks like replacing 1/8" with 1/4" at all is putting you in danger of having the pipe blow out due to much lower pressure ratings. Replacing it with something thinner-wall than ACR or type L would be even more in danger of that (no 1/4" is listed in type M on [other charts I looked at...](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/copper-tubes-dimensions-pressure-d_84.html)